# How to show pdf page in webview using html5 in android

Tags: android, html, pdf, blackberry, webview

Currently I'm using pdfrenderer library to render pdf page and convert that page into image and showing in a view.

In this case we can't copy text from pdf page. I want to create a single project which should support both blackberry(Lastest blackberry os run android apps as well) and android.

Most of the libraries which is available are not compatible with blackberry os.

To support both, i want to load pdf file in webview using html5. Is there any way to achive this.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [pdf.js](https://github.com/Marak/pdf.js/) can help you.
I've recently search a lot about javascript pdf reader and found this as the best available solution. But I should mention that it still needs a lot to do to be a good solution

Comment: I think , pdf.js just converting pdf file into image. can't able to search text, highlight etc.

Comment: No, I recommend you(@DAX) download the whole [project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/archive/master.zip), and there is a sample in the **web** directory. It searches too. As I found out, PDF.js renders pdf to canvas and puts a text layer over canvas.